# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory NodeJS

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to build a simple cli app, but I'm getting file not found. The app runs well if I run it in the same directory as the file.

after installing the app globally, it can't find the file.`npm i -g .`

```
$ tran

 Hello World CLI
```

But if switch directories, I get file not found

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './hello
```

bin/index.js

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

import { hello } from '../index.js';

console.log(hello());
```

index.js

```
import fs from 'fs';

export function hello() {
  return fs.readFileSync('./hello', 'utf8');
}
```

package.json

```
"bin": {
  "tran": "./bin/index.js"
},
"type": "module",
```

Also tried using `path`

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

export function hello() {
  return fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(path.dirname(''),'./hello'), 'utf8');
}
```

Comment: shouldn't fs read from current directory of the index.js file?

Comment: This error has to do with the bundler not able to find files referred. With Parcel, I would use ./../index.js instead of ../index.js in import statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fs.readFileSync` resolves relative paths basing on the current process directory (i.e. `process.cwd()`). To access a file in the same directory as the current module (the module that contains the `import`) you can create URL based on the current URL plus a relative part in the form

```js
new URL(relativePath, import.meta.url)
```

So, in the case of your index.js:

```js
import fs from 'fs';

export function hello() {
  return fs.readFileSync(new URL('hello', import.meta.url), 'utf8');
}
```

Comment: Man. You must be a God. You just saved my day